# How to print multiple icons in Uikit?

Tags: javascript, getuikit

Here is a code which i am using to print multiple icons using a loop which may not be a conventional method when you are using the UIkit but it is not printing the icon 10 times.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kwku2ndy/)

```
var ic = document.createElement('a');

ic.setAttribute("uk-icon","icon:heart");

var main = document.getElementById("lol");

for(var i = 0; i < 10; ++i){

      main.appendChild(ic);
}
```

References/Documentation:
[UiKit icons](https://getuikit.com/docs/icon)

[Uikit Javascript Documentation](https://getuikit.com/docs/javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this you wanted ???
fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pnfh3v4m/

```
var main = document.getElementById("lol");
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        var ic = document.createElement('a');
        ic.setAttribute("uk-icon","icon:heart");
        main.appendChild(ic);

}
```

Comment: yes that worked, can you please go through the uikit icons link and give the suitable way to implement this?

Comment: for this OP this will be the solution. you are doing it correctly.